# Are the Wonder Twins still around?

Tags: dc, wonder-twins

I'm reading the Wikipedia article on the Wonder Twins, and I see that the last update for them in the comics was in Extreme Justice in 1995. They also appeared as a pastiche of the heroes called Downpour and Shifter in Justice League Unlimited.

Are these characters still in use today in the DC Universe? Or are they still just the comedy relief they always were in the Super Friends of the 1970's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Wonder Twins have yet to make their reappearance in the DCnU, New 52 series.**

But considering how powerful the characters had become since their days as comic relief on the Superfriends, it stands to reason, DC will eventually trot them out again, either as part of Earth-16, Young Justice storylines (the animated ones) or as part of the Earth-2 stories if they want to keep them active but not part of the mainstream continuity. DC does have 50 other Earths to choose from.

Their revamp made them amazingly powerful and easily able to fit into the DCnU as aliens with powers beyond those of mortal men (DC really likes that trope). Zan's power to become a fluid now includes any solid, vapor or gaseous form of any kind of liquid including ammonia, water or even acid. Jana's shapeshifting power allows her to take on the form of any animal she knows the name of and can take on any special properties as well. She became a Kryptonian animal and gained its properties AND its superpowers under a yellow sun. They are formidable to say the least.

Despite their humble origin, their time in the Young Justice comic and the badly done Extreme Justice, did give people a chance to see them again and they were reasonably well received. I would not count them out yet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know their standing in The New 52 multiverse. Apart from the Extreme Justice appearance, I can only recall Zan appearing in a few panels in Kingdom Come (Earth-22). Even this might just be a gag from Alex Ross.

Most likely, they remain in their state as comic relief and only appear again for nostalgia.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the actual issues, but apparently updated versions of Zan & Jayna appeared in late issues of Young Justice in 2002.

http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/0/6033/1041402-wondertwins_new.jpg